Calculus of variations infinum problem
We are given a functional $J: AC[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$, such that $J(x) = \int_{0}^{1}{\dot{x}^6(x - t^{1/3})^2dt}$. Show that $\inf\{J(x) : x \in AC[0, 1], x(0) = 0, x(1) = 1\} < \inf\{J(x): x \in Lip[0, 1], x(0) = 0, x(1) = 1\}$.
I have been trying to explicitly solve the equations, however I came up with the thought that I just need to give an example of the function from the $AC[0, 1]$ so that it cannot be reached for $Lip[0, 1]$.

It seems to me that both infimums are 0. Is this an exercise from a book or something you came out with?

From the lecturer. I found $t^{1/3}$ as an obvious answer, however, it is not Lip!

My idea didn’t work, I’m sorry. If I get another idea I’ll let you know.

I have been able to find a sequence of Lipschitz functions $x_n$ such that $x_n\to t^{1/3}$ but $J(x_n)\to\infty$. I think that the problem with Lipschitz functions is that their dervative must be bounded, so $x_n-t^{1/3}$ must have some support in $[0,\epsilon)$, but in order for $x_n\to t^{1/3}$, $\dot{x}_n \to\infty$ in a neighborhood of $0$ in such a way that $\dot{x}^6$ blows up faster than $(x_n-t^{1/3})^2$ shrinks and the resulting integral blow up as $n\to\infty$

@whpowell96 why can't we just make this function constant in the 0-neighbourhood?

@whpowell96 does it prove that this is the right answer? What is this sequence btw?

The sequence was $$x_n(t) = \begin{cases} n^{2/3}t, & [0,1/n] \ t^{1/3}, & (1/n,1]\end{cases}.$$ It converges to $t^{1/3}$ pointwise and $x_n(t) - t^{1/3}$ is only supported on $[0,1/n]$. Despite this, $J(x_n)$ grows without bound as $n\to\infty$.
